# Difference between "Kofax KTA Transformation Designer" and "Kofax KTA Designer"

Tags: kofax

What is the difference between KTA designer and KTA Transformation Designer(TD)?

Answer (score 1):

KTA designer is a low-code/no-code interface. Total Agility designer
features a drag and drop interface for creating solutions and
facilitating the configuration of business logic (rules, forms,
conditions, loops, etc.).

Whereas, The KTA TD or Transformation designer is an advanced tool to setup and enable advance features of classification, extraction using machine learning trainable group locators, NLP .. etc